# Replacing dir with to custom utility in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-registry, ms-dos

I'm using Windows 7 and would like to change the default dir command in the Command Prompt to another program.

I've tried putting both dir.exe and dir.bat in the C:\ root but when I type dir it doesn't launch the program. Does anyone know to launch it after I type dir? It might be a registry change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read over this post as well in case you are looking for something like a command line alias in Windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt .... there are several answers here that may suffice for your needs.

Comment: Try to put it in `C:\Windows`, because it is in the `%path%` variable.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like to change the default `dir` command in the Command Prompt to another program.

You can't, at least not directly, as `dir` is built in to`cmd.exe`:

> **Internal commands**
>
> The Windows CMD shell CMD.exe contains a number of 'internal'
>   commands, additional 'external' commands are also supplied as separate
>   executable files. External commands are generally stored in the
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32 folder, this folder is part of the system PATH .
>
> This arrangement means that both internal and external commands are
>   always available no matter what your current directory happens to be.
>
> ASSOC, BREAK, CALL ,CD/CHDIR, CLS, COLOR, COPY, DATE, DEL, DIR, DPATH,
>   ECHO, ENDLOCAL, ERASE, EXIT, FOR, FTYPE, GOTO, IF, KEYS, MD/MKDIR,
>   MKLINK (vista and above), MOVE, PATH, PAUSE, POPD, PROMPT, PUSHD, REM,
>   REN/RENAME, RD/RMDIR, SET, SETLOCAL, SHIFT, START, TIME, TITLE, TYPE,
>   VER, VERIFY, VOL

However ...

> It is possible for a system to have an internal command and an
>   external command with the same name. If you have a command called
>   DATE.exe and want to run that in preference to the internal DATE
>   command, use the full pathname to the file e.g. C:\utils\date.exe even
>   if your current directory is C:\utils\

Source [Internal commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html)

So instead of using just `dir` you have to use the full name of your replacement, in your case:

```
c:\dir.exe
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [syntax-internal](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) - Internal commands

Comment: I usually rename it to something similar and put it in a location that is in the path environment. For example, the linux command ls is not present in cmd, so you could name it ls.exe and place it in c:\windows\system32 and now you can use ls to perform the dir.